# initWithUrl does not work with question marks

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4

```
NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlString];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[self.webview loadRequest:requestObj];
```

I have the code above. For some reason, urls like "http://linkedin.com/view?id=3" for example i.e. urls with a question mark aren't loaded properly in the webview. What should I do?

Comment: What is a `PLWebViewController`? What exactly happens? Are you sure your `NSURL` is a real, valid object, that has represents a valid URL? How did you determine that it's the question mark that's causing the problem?

Comment: Can you post the code where you instantiate linkedin

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://your_url.com"];
    NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"arg1=%@&arg2=%@", @"val1",@"val2"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: url];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [webView loadRequest: request];
```

Comment: Please don't try this.  (1) `?` in a URL is fine, according to RFCs 1808, 1738, and 2732.  (2) you are `POST`ing when you should be `GET`ting. (3) You are using `stringWithFormat:` for no reason.

Comment: Presumably, `@"val1"` and `@"val2"` represent variables, and as such should probably not be written as `NSString` literals.